# Element destination

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I created a html page and inserted a textbox. I would like to know a textbox destination in the page from javascript function? Example textbox's top is 100 px like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("id1").offsetTop);
};
```

where `id1` is the id of the textbox you need to triangulate.